# Sending to and receiving from different processes in MPI

Tags: c, mpi

So I'm writing a program to bounce a "virtual ball" between processes. The root process i.e. the task with rank 0 initializes the game and then sends it to a random process which is determined by `rand() % size` (with the random number generated seeded by the initial rank).

I've tried doing:

`int rnk= rand() % size;
 MPI_Send(&ball,1, MPI_INT, rnk, MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

This sends the ball to the next random process but upon running this the code is held up by the blocking MPI_Send. I've just begun parallel programming so I don't have enough grasp of this. How do I send to a random process and then they further send it to any random process?

Any pointers, tips, books and tutorials are welcome.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] of what you have tried.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348900/mpi-recv-from-an-unknown-source

Comment: Okay so the trouble was that one of the MPI processes was getting hung, due to a race condition. I resolved that and the program ran as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue here if the root initially tries to send to itself (which can happen since rand()%size could be zero).

- if you post the receive first on the root then it will block as it will never get to the send call (as pointed out by @Gregor above);
- however, if you post the send first on the root then there is no guarantee that it will ever progress to the receive call as MPI_Send() is *not* guaranteed to be asynchronous (i.e. it could be implemented as a synchronous send which will wait forever for a matching receive).

You need to either ensure that the sender never sends to itself, or use non-blocking sends (or non-blocking receives) to avoid the potential deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MPI_Recv` with `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` as source (see comment by francis).

Make sure that you first call `MPI_Recv` in all processes except for the root, which first needs to send.